# Can a non piecewise function have continuity on only one of its sides?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

For a given non piecewise function f(x) can it happen that $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) \not= f(a)$, $\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = f(a)$?

Comment: That depends upon how you define "piecewise function".

Comment: The situation you describe is known as càglàd. It is empirically less common than its time-reversed cousin, [càglàd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g). As @AnotherUser pointed out, whether these are necessarily piecewise might depend on how you define "piecewise."

Comment: Piecewise would be as in "made up of several subfunctions that define how it behaves at different intervals in its domain"

Comment: The floor function works (reversing approaches). Is that piecewise to you? I guess every function is technically a piecewise function.

Comment: How does that definition of "piecewise" rule out any of our ordinary continuous functions? Even $f(x)=0$ has a piecewise definition.